# Prove this Matrix is Positive Definite

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose

u $ \neq 0 \in$ $\mathbb{C}^m$

$\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

For what Values of $\alpha$ is $I + \alpha uu^{*}$ Positive Definite?

Progress so far :

$\forall x \neq 0 \in \mathbb{C}^m$

We Have $x^*Ix$ > 0

I cant determine the values of $\alpha$ which make the overall quantity Positive Definite however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$
x^*\alpha uu^* x = \alpha (x^*u)(u^*x) = \alpha (x^*u)\overline{(x^*u)} = \alpha |x^*u|^2
$$

then use Cauchy-Schwarz; this will yield an $|x|^2$ to match $x^*Ix = |x|^2$.

Comment: I actually reached this conclusion as well but I'm not sure how to eliminate the x from the problem since I cant give a final answer in terms of arbitrary x.

Comment: Use Cauchy-Schwarz (see my edited answer for more).